# LinearProgress bar not having the same length as navbar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using LinearProgress by Material UI and I made a custom ColoredLinearProgress just to change its color:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';

class ColoredLinearProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return <LinearProgress {...this.props} classes={{colorPrimary: classes.colorPrimary, barColorPrimary: classes.barColorPrimary}}/>;
  }
}

const styles = props => ({
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#FD8907',
  },
  barColorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#EEC291',
  }
});

export default  withStyles(styles)(ColoredLinearProgress);
```

Then I included it on the render of my page like this:

```
return(   
                <div>
                {this.state.loading ? <ColoredLinearProgress /> : null}  
                // more code
                </div>
```

Turns out the ColoredLinearProgress displays at a shorter length than the navbar.
My navbar is called from the App.js

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Suspense fallback={(<div>Loading</div>)}>
          <Navbar updateUsername={this.updateUsername} username={this.state.username}/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={MyPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>    
  );
}
```

I've tracked down the issue and it seems to be inside my Navbar render

```
    return(
            <nav>
                <Link to={{pathname: "/"}}>
                    <img src={logo} alt="Home" id="logo"/>
                </Link>
                <div className="dropdown">
                    <button className="navbar_item" onClick={this.showlogin}>{t('navbar.signIn')}</button>
                </div>
                {/* If I comment the following 'Link' the LinearProgress shows perfectly! */}
                <Link to={{pathname: "/SignUp"}}>
                    <p className="navbar_item" id="sign_up" onClick={() => this.showlogin(true)}>{t('navbar.signUp')}</p>
                </Link>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

If I comment the last Link element, the linearprogress shows fine, otherwise it displays shorter than the navbar right before that link element. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was apparently because of the 'p' element so I changed it to button.

```
    return(
            <nav>
                <Link to={{pathname: "/"}}>
                    <img src={logo} alt="Home" id="logo"/>
                </Link>
                <div className="dropdown">
                    <button className="navbar_item" onClick={this.showlogin}>{t('navbar.signIn')}</button>
                </div>
                {/* If I comment the following 'Link' the LinearProgress shows perfectly! */}
                <Link to={{pathname: "/SignUp"}}>
                    <button className="navbar_item" id="sign_up" onClick={() => this.showlogin(true)}>{t('navbar.signUp')}</button>
                </Link>
        </nav>
    )
}
```